# Doxygen support

Tags: documentation

I'm creating some doxygen in Emacs and I can't find any mode for this purpose. The only mode I found is the below project which seems too old (last release from 2007!). Do you any alternatives to this mode?

http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/

Emacs version in use: GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2

Comment: No. Are you asking because it is not working?

Comment: I didn't try it since it was released back in 2007 and doesn't seem in active development.

Comment: Why not try it and update the question if you encounter problems?

Comment: It's too old and inactive project. I was asking just in case there's something  more actual and in continuos development.

Comment: Old and inactive are not sufficient reasons for something not working. Depending on the language there could be many modern alternatives. Most newer languages have built in documentation features. Since you have not provided details of what languages and how you want to use the documentation, it is hard to recommend specifics.

Answer (score 4):

I just released a package for highlighting Doxygen comments. In addition to highlighting Doxygen commands and their arguments, it highlights code examples according to the language they are written in.

See [highlight-doxygen](https://github.com/Lindydancer/highlight-doxygen) for more information.